# X509Certificate LoadCertificateFromBlob Cryptography Exception in Linux

Tags: linux, wcf, mono, cryptography, x509certificate

I am trying to run an app that I complied in Windows VS Community Edition .NET4.0 in linux using Wine.  The application works fine in Windows, but in Linux it gets stuck when referencing the private certificate:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unknown error "-2146885623". 
       at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._QueryCertBlobType(Byte[] rawData)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
       at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
       at NS.Program.ConfigureCredentials[T](ClientBase`1 c) in f:\program\Program.cs:line 458
       at NS.Program.Client(Boolean getBinding) in f:\program\Program.cs:line 148
       at NS.Program.Main(String[] args) in f:\program\Program.cs:line 63
```

Here is the code:

```
byte[] privateKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"PrivateCertificate.pfx");
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(
     privateKey,
     "********",
     X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
);
```

I saw some articles referring to 'Load User Profile', but that's an IIS thing.  I verified permissions on PrivateCertificate.pfx -rw-rw-r-- myuser:myuser.

I also tried mono-devel, mono-complete and wine-mono, but all of those threw errors on missing class references before even coming close to hitting the above mentioned (X509Certificate) lines.

Any ideas on why this wouldn't work in Linux?

Comment: Which linux distro and versions of wine and mono are you using?

Comment: ubuntu, wine1.7, mono (whatever the latest version was) I have since removed as it caused more problems than solved, but here are the commands I ran for mono installs: sudo apt-get install (mono-devel | mono-complete | wine-mono4.5.6).